# How to run Windows Script File in Windows service recovery

Tags: service, recovery, windows-scripting, wsh

I have written a script(.wsf) to trigger an Email when a particular service fails. For first,second and subsequent failure i have given run a program and added my .wsf file in that tab. Yet i am not getting Email alert. May i know what i should do to execute that.

Steps taken : ( But no result/didn't work)

1) In the run a program tab , gave the complete path of the script
2) Written a bat file and which inturn call that .wsf file
3)Gave the path of administrator cmd.exe path in run a program tab and gave the path of the script file in the command line parameters tab.

Note: I have executed this separately in cmd.exe and it worked by sending Email alert.

To make service fail i manually stopped it, restarted it yet notify didn't turned up. Please let me know what i should do further in executing the script from windows service recovery tab. I hereby added my script too.

```
<job>
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim WshShell
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet smtp.sample.com 25"

WshShell.Sendkeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "EHLO sample.com"
WshShell.Sendkeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "MAIL FROM:alice@sample.com"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "RCPT TO:bob@sample.com"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "DATA"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "Subject: Test Email"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "Body-Test Email executed by running script"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "."
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Quit 
</script>
</job>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to automate a process with tools designed for desktop usage from a task executed from a system service and which runs in a limited session, .... if it works you have big luck.

There are a lot of problems involved in getting it working, and not sure if it will work on new versions of the system.

If a scripted telnet session is needed, your better option will be plink command line tool from putty package.

Or you can try with CDO

```
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "alice@sample.com"
objEmail.To = "bob@sample.com"
objEmail.Subject = "Service is down" 
objEmail.Textbody = "The service has failed"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.sample.com" 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send
```